# Fortify com.fortify.dev.ant.SCAListener could not be loaded because of an invalid dependency

Tags: fortify, fortify-source

Has anyone seen this issue before? I tried running fortify with verbose on but all I get is: Compiler execution failed (exit code: 1)

I am trying to run fortify source with an ant script.

EDIT:

```
sourceanalyzer -b name -source 1.5 ant -D(some var) target
```

I have no problem when I do:

```
sourceanalyzer -b name -clean
```

Comment: I assume the ant script works when you call it directly?  Can also show how you are calling Fortify (are you doing with the ant tasks or having sourceanalyzer call ant?).

Comment: yeah I can call the ant script directly, I'm having source analyzer call ant, see edit

Comment: the `-D(some var) is for ant?  Everythign after ant should be for the ant script.  Try this `sourceanalyzer -b name -source 1.5 -verbose -debug -logfile log.txt ant -D(some var) target` anything useful in the log file?

Comment: No I don't see anything useful, other than the error code and error statement above.